# /usr/bin/env: ‘sh\r’: No such file or directory in linux while running react-native

Tags: android, linux, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I'm windows user transitioning to linux. I've set up environment and everything according to docs but when i run npx react-native run-android i'm getting following error. What is the solution? I've tried installing dos2unix nad running `dos2unix ./gradlew clean` for testing and it says gradlew not found. Envoirnment variables and paths are set correctly.

```
└─$ npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1393 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
/usr/bin/env: ‘sh\r’: No such file or directory
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/usr/bin/env: ‘sh\r’: No such file or directory
at makeError (/media/muaz/Studios/stylon/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /media/muaz/Studios/stylon/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/media/muaz/Studios/stylon/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/media/muaz/Studios/stylon/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

P.S I intend to use both OSes. I have dual boot system.

Answer (score 4):

This worked:

install dos2unix

```
cd android && dos2unix ./gradlew
```

Comment: Worked for me. I had to install dos2unix first. Then `cd android`. Then `dos2unix ./gradlew`